# How do I parse an element off a rss feed in java

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, rss

Im trying to build an app that could retrieve elements from a RSS feed. How do I output all the  items?  This is what I have so far.

```
public static String readRSS(String urlAddress){

  try{
     URL rssUrl = new URL(urlAddress);
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(rssUrl.openStream()));
     String sourceCode = "";
     String line;
     while ((line= in.readLine())!= null){
        if (line.contains("<title>")){
           int firstPos = line.indexOf("<title>");
           String temp = line.substring(firstPos);
           temp = temp.replace("<title>", "");
           int lastPos = temp.indexOf("</title>");
           temp = temp.substring(0,lastPos);
           sourceCode += temp+"\n";
        }
     }
     in.close();
     return sourceCode;
  }catch (MalformedURLException ue){
     System.out.println("Malformed URL");
  }catch (IOException ioe){
     System.out.println("Something went wrong reading the content");
  }
  return null;
}
```

Basically, at this point I only retrieve the first  element of the RSS feed.  What am I doing wrong here? I want to retrieve all the  elements.  Please help me.  Thank you.

Comment: did you forget to add further code ? because line =  looks like a bug to me

Comment: Oh my mistake. I was trying different things and forgot to remove it.  I just changed it.

Comment: logic inside while loop is wrong ! why don't you use xml parser to parse this. you could use dom parser.